# In Firebase, with FlutterFire, how to initialize a secondary app on iOS? InitializeApp with options give GOOGLE_APP_ID error

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

In a Flutter app, using FlutterFire to connect to Firebase, is used this code to connect to a secondary storage:

```
  FirebaseApp hostApp;
  try {
    hostApp = Firebase.app("HostApp");
  } catch (e) {
    hostApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'HostApp',
        options: FirebaseOptions(
            appId: ConfigService.hostAppId,
            apiKey: ConfigService.hostApiKey,
            authDomain: ConfigService.hostAuthDomain,
            storageBucket: ConfigService.hostStorageBucket,
            projectId: ConfigService.hostProjectId,
            messagingSenderId: ConfigService.hostMessagingSenderId));
  }
  _storage = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(app: hostApp);
```

on Android works, but on iOS gives this error on initializeApp:

```
    7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000009] The GOOGLE_APP_ID either in the plist file 'GoogleService-Info.plist' or the one set in the customized options is invalid.
If you are using the plist file, use the iOS version of bundle identifier to download the file, and do not manually edit the GOOGLE_APP_ID. You may change your app's bundle identifier to 'app.myapp'.
Or you can download a new configuration file that matches your bundle identifier from https://console.firebase.google.com/ and replace the current one.
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'
        *** First throw call stack:
        (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c627b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c08c141 objc_exception_throw + 48
            2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c690625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
            3   Runner                              0x00000001088fb926 +[FIRApp addAppToAppDictionary:] + 278
            4   Runner                              0x00000001088fab12 +[FIRApp configureWithName:options:] + 1266
```

I've added iosClientId and iosBundleId options, but gives the same error.

The default app is already initialized:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

The bundle identifier is correct.

how to initialize a secondary app on iOS?

Comment: From where are you getting all these values ? (appId: ConfigService.hostAppId,
            apiKey: ConfigService.hostApiKey,
            authDomain: ConfigService.hostAuthDomain,
            storageBucket: ConfigService.hostStorageBucket,
            projectId: ConfigService.hostProjectId,
            messagingSenderId: ConfigService.hostMessagingSenderId)

Comment: What do you mean by initializing a secondary app ?

Comment: These values are from Firebase project settings (or in google-services.json).

Comment: The app connects to another Firebase project. This is what I say "secondary app".

Answer (score 1):

I was using a web appId (e.g. 1:12345678:**web**:123abcd456efg78). I have changed the appId for a iOS appId and it works.

On Android works, but on iOS give this error.

Comment: Can we use FirebaseOptions to initialize default app also ? Or it should only be used for initializing secondary app ?  Is it possible to remove google-services.json and do the initialization of default app using FirebaseOptions ?

Comment: No, it can't. On the Firebase.initializeApp help says: "the default app instance cannot be initialized here and should be created using the platform Firebase integration"